# Only one value is returned from an expression containing "exp" instead of an array of values

Tags: python, sympy

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
from matplotlib import font_manager, rc
font_name = font_manager.FontProperties(fname="c:/Windows/Fonts/malgun.ttf").get_name()
rc('font', family=font_name)

t = np.linspace(0,300)
C0 = 0
Q = 0.1
V = 1
C1 = 0
S = 0.4 * exp(-0.001*t)

Y = (C0 * exp((-Q*t)/V)) + ((C1 * Q + S)/Q) - (exp((-Q*t)/V) * ((C1 * Q + S)/Q))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, Y , 'go--', label='decay source')
plt.title('decay source')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('time(s)')
plt.ylabel('density(mg/s)')
plt.show()
```

[See the error message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idtBS.png)

I want to draw a graph, but I can't because only one Y came out.

If you look at the Y value through the print, you can see that exp is not calculated. How can I solve this?

Comment: Well, sympy functions don't work with numpy arrays (and numpy doesn't work with sympy's symbols). Just remove `import sympy` as you aren't really using it. And do use `np.exp` for the exponentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `np.exp(array)` function to calculate the exponential of all elements in array
`(-Q*t)/V`